# SQL - Get Next and Previous X records

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to use a query in postgresql that can get the previous and next X number of records based on a starting record ID used for some pagination. Getting only 1 next or previous is not that hard but that's not what I need.

I've found some queries that are close but I don't know enough about PostgreSQL queries to do these types of complex queries.

This query below I tried and changed to work, but seems to bring back only the previous and next item of an ID and *all* the records.

But I need to be able to give it a starting point providing an ID such as in the `WHERE` clause and only get 10 previous and 10 next records if they exists. Is this possible to do in sql alone?

```
SELECT
  m.med_id AS id,
  coalesce(
      LEAD(m.med_id) OVER (ORDER BY m.med_id DESC),
      (select med.med_id from media as med order by med.med_id desc limit 1)
  ) AS nextitemid,
  coalesce(
      LAG(m.med_id) OVER (ORDER BY m.med_id DESC),
      (select med.med_id from media as med order by med.med_id asc limit 1)
  ) AS previtemid
FROM media m
WHERE m.post_type = 1
ORDER BY m.med_id DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Any help would be appreciated and it can be any type of sql solution that would accomplish this.

Desired output I believe would be from an example of 100 items given 50 as the ID starting point provided in the query.

```
|previtemids|nextitemids|
    49           51
    48           52
    47           53
    46           54
    45           55
    44           56
    43           57
    42           58 
    41           59 
    40           60
```

I've come close but haven't been able to get it in one query. Answers that are close to my scenario are more helpful than generic answers.

Comment: Do you want the 10 previous and 10 next records in columns, or a separate row for each record?

Comment: Hmm good question @Alex I'll be reading it from PHP into an array. Maybe columns might be easier?

Comment: Could you please post an example of your desired output?

Comment: @alex I provided an example

Comment: i take that back. It's almost working but not quite

Answer (score 0):

```
with numbered as(
   select your_table.*, row_number() over(order by id) as rn from your_table 
)
SELECT previous.id, next.id FROM 
(SELECT id, row_number() over(order by id) as inner_rn FROM numbered where rn between (select rn from numbered WHERE id = 12) - 5 and (select rn from numbered WHERE id = 12) -1) previous
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT id, row_number() over(order by id) as inner_rn FROM numbered where rn between (select rn from numbered WHERE id = 12) + 1 and (select rn from numbered WHERE id = 12) + 5) next
ON previous.inner_rn = next.inner_rn
```

If I correct understood you need this

here 12 is `starting point providing an ID` and 5 is Next and Previous X records

(Note: for example, if there is not 10 previous row, but there is 10 next rows, and you need fill out missed values  with NULLs, then use `FULL JOIN` instead of  `INNER JOIN` )

Comment: So that did not really yield the correct results. The query I had was a little closer to what I needed. Just doesn't work as expected.

Comment: So do you need previous and next x ids in different two columns? (as in your edited example ?)

Comment: I think that would be ideal

Comment: Ok my query is close but not quite.

Comment: That is closer, I have another table i need to join with the main table in the example. See my old query above in my question to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how this is done, we use this to generate 100 random digits between 0-1000..

```
SELECT
  trunc(random()*1000) AS x
FROM generate_series(1,100);
```

Now we given an id of 80, we can find the range of 70-90 here.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT rank() OVER (ORDER BY x) AS dr, x
  FROM (
    SELECT
      trunc(random()*1000) AS x
    FROM generate_series(1,100)
  ) AS t
) AS t
WHERE dr BETWEEN 80-10 AND 80+10;

 dr |  x  
----+-----
 70 | 702
 71 | 706
 72 | 718
 73 | 734
 74 | 751
 75 | 756
 76 | 774
 77 | 778
 78 | 805
 79 | 813
 80 | 829
 81 | 833
 82 | 839
 83 | 852
 84 | 853
 85 | 872
 86 | 884
 86 | 884
 88 | 892
 89 | 897
 90 | 905
(21 rows)
```

But I wouldn't do this. I would do pagination by passing an id, and the desired rows. And only permit moving forward. Store the previous results on the browser.